# How do we calculate the new values for theta(weights?) in the output layer after backpropagation?

Tags: neural-network

I'm currently trying to catch up with Andrew Ng's machine learning course on Coursera and I'm having a little bit of trouble...

In his backpropagation video he explains that we need to calculate big_delta

`big_delta = big_delta + delta(l+1) * a(l)^t` for all layers l

However, how do I calculate big_delta for the output layer when I don't have delta(l+1)?

The video where he explains this is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmfpS5fKFeY

I'm lost.

Answer (score 3):

Delta at the output layer is

```
delta = (<expected signal> - <calculated_signal>) * dA(<calculated_signal>)
```

where dA is the derivative of the activation function that has been applied to the signal. Sigmoid is commonly use as activation function and its derivative is really simple:

```
dS(x) = x(1-x)
```

The "big_delta"-equalization you have there is used for all the other layers, and the deltas you get are needed when updating the weights and biases.

[Here's](http://www.learnartificialneuralnetworks.com/backpropagation.html) some (hard-to-read) mathematics/algoritmics of the backpropagation.

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify the eq's a bit, IF Sigmoid is used as an activation function, the delta at the output layer is calculated as

```
delta = (<expected signal> - <calculated_signal>) * <calculated_signal> * (1 - <calculated_signal>)
```

Comment: Ohhh, I should've figured that one out! Thank you. Just to be 100%, x in this case is the output of the hidden layer, not the input from training set. Right?

Comment: @EssamAl-Mansouri x is the <calculated_signal> as shown in the first equalization. If A = Sigmoid ( =S(x) ), then dA(x) = dS(x) = <calculated_signal> * (1-<calculated_signal>).

Comment: @EssamAl-Mansouri I added some clarification for the answer.